# Ubuntu 15.04: Elasticsearch service doesn't start

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

I followed the first part from the tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-4-on-ubuntu-14-04) to install Elasticsearch. I didn't install java because I already have that installed with other java programs running.

```
sudo service elasticsearch restart
```

Doesn't output anything.

```
sudo service elasticsearch status
```

Outputs the following:

> ● elasticsearch.service - Starts and stops a single elasticsearch
>   instance on this system    Loaded: loaded
>   (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled; vendor
>   preset: enabled)    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat
>   2015-06-06 08:33:20 EET; 1s ago
>        Docs: http://www.elasticsearch.org   Process: 17111 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
>   -Des.default.config=$CONF_FILE -Des.default.path.home=$ES_HOME -Des.default.path.logs=$LOG_DIR -Des.default.path.data=$DATA_DIR -Des.default.path.work=$WORK_DIR -Des.default.path.conf=$CONF_DIR (code=exited, status=3)  Main PID: 17111 (code=exited, status=3)
>
> Jun 06 08:33:20 mohammed-xubuntu elasticsearch[17111]: ... 4 more 
>   Jun 06 08:33:20 mohammed-xubuntu elasticsearch[17111]: log4j:WARN No appender... 
>   Jun 06 08:33:20 mohammed-xubuntu elasticsearch[17111]: log4j:WARN Please init... 
>   Jun 06 08:33:20 mohammed-xubuntu elasticsearch[17111]: log4j:WARN See http://... 
>   Jun 06 08:33:20 mohammed-xubuntu elasticsearch[17111]: {1.5.2}: Initializatio... 
>   Jun 06 08:33:20 mohammed-xubuntu elasticsearch[17111]: -
>   ElasticsearchIllegal... 
>   Jun 06 08:33:20 mohammed-xubuntu elasticsearch[17111]: AccessDeniedException[... 
>   Jun 06 08:33:20 mohammed-xubuntu systemd[1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-4-on-ubuntu-14-04): elasticsearch.service: main pro...D 
>   Jun 06 08:33:20 mohammed-xubuntu systemd[1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-4-on-ubuntu-14-04): Unit elasticsearch.service ente.... 
>   Jun 06 08:33:20 mohammed-xubuntu systemd[1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-4-on-ubuntu-14-04):
>   elasticsearch.service failed. Hint: 
>   Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.

It says I should pass **-l** option somewhere to get the full output though I don't know where exactly.

Answer (score 5):

This is a known issue with Elasticsearch on Ubuntu 15.04. There is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10671). The temporary fix:

> As a workaround you can uncomment the paths in the /etc/default/elasticsearch file and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 15.10, in addition to uncommenting the DIRS I also had to uncomment `START_DAEMON` to `true` on `/etc/default/elasticsearch` to get it to `start`.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the rc.d symlinks were not installed, even when installing using elastic.co packages.  Also disabling systemd for elasticsearch/

I ran the following:

```
update-rc.d elasticsearch defaults
update-rc.d logstash defaults
update-rc.d kibana defaults
systemctl disable elasticsearch
```